# linux 'cannot execute binary file' on every executable I compile, chmod 777 doesn't help

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I am running red had linux 7.3 (old, I know), and for the past few months I've been learning assembly programming, writing small programs and compiling with nasm.  For months, things have been going fine, and now for some unknown reason, I cannot execute any programs that I compile.

```
nasm file.s //used to work just fine, then I'd execute ./file
```

now, when I run ./file, first I get "permission denied", which never used to happen before.  then, once i chmod +777 file, I get "cannot execute binary file".

I have NO IDEA why this is happening, but it is extremely frustrating since NOTHING I compile will run anymore.

Logging in as root doesn't change anything.
All suggestions are welcome, THANK YOU!!

Comment: Please post output from `ls -l` after you compiled the file. The "cannot execute" error might be just caused by an incorrectly generated binary (not linked, wrong architecture, whatever...).

Answer (score 3):

nasm does not produce an executable, but just an object file (like gcc -c would). You still need to run the linker on it.

N.B.: “0777 is almost always wrong.”

Answer (score 2):

Run the `file` command on your binaries and make sure they're identified correctly as executables.

Also try the `ldd` command. It will very likely fail for the exact same reason, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the file system you operate on is mounted with the `noexec` option. You could check that by doing `mount | grep noexec` and see if your current working directory suffers from that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I typed that and nothing was returned.

Comment: That sounds odd, but I'm not familiar with Red Hat. What is the output of plain `mount`, please?

Comment: If this were the problem, the error message would have been "Permission denied", not "Cannot execute binary file".

Answer (score 1):

"Cannot execute binary file" is the `strerror(3)` message for the error code `ENOEXEC`.  That has a very specific meaning: (quoting the manpage for `execve(2)`)

```
[ENOEXEC]          The new process file has the appropriate access
                   permission, but has an unrecognized format
                   (e.g., an invalid magic number in its header).
```

So what that means is, your `nasm` invocation is not producing an executable, but rather something else.  As John Kugelman suggests, the `file` command will tell you what it is (user502515 is very likely to be right that it's an unlinked object file, but I have never used nasm myself so I don't know).

BTW, you'll do yourself a favor if you learn GAS/"AT&T" assembly syntax now, rather than when you need to rewrite your assembly code for an architecture that doesn't do Intel bizarro-world syntax.  And I *do* hope you're using assembly only for inner-loop subroutines that actually *need* to be hand-optimized.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me. After running

`file <executable name>`

it output `<file name> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped`

And the problem was that I was trying to run a **64 bit** app on a **32 bit** machine!

Answer (score 0):

You may try looking into /var/log for some change in the system from this start to happen.